# Python parallelised correlation slower than single process correlation

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, correlation

I wanted to parallelize `df.corr()` using `multiprocessing` module in Python. I'm taking one column and computing correlation values with rest all columns in one process and second column with rest other columns in another process. I'm continuing in this fashion to fill the upper traingle of correlation matrix by stacking up the result rows from all the processes.

I took sample data of shape `(678461, 210)` and tried my parallelized method and `df.corr()` and got running time of `214.40s` and `42.64s` respectively. So, my parallelized method is taking more time.

Is there a way to improve this?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import *

def _correlation(args):

    i, mat, mask = args
    ac = mat[i]

    arr = []

    for j in range(len(mat)):  
        if i > j:
            continue

        bc = mat[j]
        valid = mask[i] & mask[j]
        if valid.sum() < 1:
            c = NA    
        elif i == j:
            c = 1.
        elif not valid.all():
            c = np.corrcoef(ac[valid], bc[valid])[0, 1]
        else:
            c = np.corrcoef(ac, bc)[0, 1]

        arr.append((j, c))

    return arr

def correlation_multi(df):

    numeric_df = df._get_numeric_data()
    cols = numeric_df.columns
    mat = numeric_df.values

    mat = pd.core.common._ensure_float64(mat).T
    K = len(cols)
    correl = np.empty((K, K), dtype=float)
    mask = np.isfinite(mat)

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

    ret_list = pool.map(_correlation, [(i, mat, mask) for i in range(len(mat))])

    for i, arr in enumerate(ret_list):
        for l in arr:
            j = l[0]
            c = l[1]

            correl[i, j] = c
            correl[j, i] = c

    return pd.DataFrame(correl, index = cols, columns = cols)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    noise  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 50)))
    noise2  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,200,size=(100000, 50)))
    df = pd.concat([noise, noise2], axis=1)

    #Single process correlation    
    start = time()
    s = df.corr()
    print('Time taken: ',time()-start)

    #Multi process correlation
    start = time()
    s1 = correlation_multi(df)
    print('Time taken: ',time()-start)
```

Answer (score 0):

The results from `_correlation` have to be moved from the worker processes to the process running the `Pool` via interprocess communication.

This means that the return data is pickled, sent to the other process, unpickled and added to the result list.
This takes time and is by nature a sequential process.

And `map` processes the returns in the order they were sent, IIRC. So if one iteration takes relatively long, other results might be stuck waiting. You could try using `imap_unordered` which yields results as soon as they arrive.